# How to do implement badge

Tags: android

I want to do implement of badge to arraylist.But I can't.

Here badge class:https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/

This github page is have an example for arraylist.It's here:https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/src/viewbadger/demo/DemoActivity.java It starts in line 290.

This is my array adapter method:

```
conversationsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<JsonObject>(this,0) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int c_position,View c_convertView,ViewGroup c_parent) {
        if (c_convertView == null) {
            c_convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars,null);
        }
        JsonObject user=getItem(c_position);
        String name=user.get("name").getAsString();
        String image_url="http://domain.com/photos/profile/thumb/"+user.get("photo").getAsString();
        TextView nameView=(TextView)c_convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweet);
        nameView.setText(name);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)c_convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Ion.with(imageView)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.twitter)
        .load(image_url);
        return c_convertView;
    }
};
ListView conversationsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.conversationList);
conversationsListView.setAdapter(conversationsAdapter);
conversationsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        //Log.w("Pos","asd"+randomAdapter.getItem(position).get("name").getAsString());
        startChat(conversationsAdapter.getItem(position));

    }
});
```

I want to add badges to each line.How can I do this ?

Comment: ViewBadger is a bit dated. My recommendation is that you figure out how it works (FrameLayout with a badge-layout over the regular layout), and code it yourself. It's not difficult. I recently did that to fix some tab views that ViewBadger could not handle.

Comment: Hmm,can you give a sample code for arraylist and tabs ?